# Using command line actions in Midori

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, midori

I'm trying to control an existing instance of Midori, I launch it with

> midori -e fullscreen

which works properly.  Then commands like

> midori -e next
>
> midori -e back

work properly.  But when I try to do

> midori -e Location www.google.com

it gives me the error

> ** (midori:1107): WARNING **: Unexpected action 'www.google.com'.

I've tried a dash, colon, double quotes around the URL, but everything gives the same error.

I know that I can just pass a URL on the command line but that launches a new instance of Midori which is what I'm trying to avoid.  Any help is appreciated!

I found another question asking this same thing but it was unanswered so I wasn't sure the proper approach to reopening it...

Answer (score 1):

Using a [full URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (including scheme) works for me. Try

```
midori -e Location https://www.google.com
```